# How can I modify an image to have colors that flow into each other and what is this effect called?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photo-editing, image-editing, adobe-photoshop-elements

I have been trying to find the name of this effect in this image [image]

Specifically, how the image has been converted to white and a spectrum of colors that flow into each other. I would like to know how to do this, what is the name of this effect so I can Google it?

Comment: It's called a masked gradient, but when used with flowing illustrated characters it's called a [Final Fantasy logo](https://tomalcockccw.files.wordpress.com/2010/11/final-fantasy-logos1.jpg)... or something that is trying to be one. :-D And I see your reference *is* the actual logo art for X. Super recognizable when used in this way, and not to be overused.

Comment: By overused I mean... well just do a Google Image Search for `JRPG logo`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**It's the Radial Gradient Tool**

Double click on layer or right click and select *Blending Options*.

[image]

Check *Gradient Overlay* and change mode to `Radial` as shown in image.

[image]

Drag your cursor above image to change the location of your gradient and change scale slider to define spread area.

[image]

**For further explanation, refer to the [official tips](https://helpx.adobe.com/in/photoshop/using/gradients.html)**

Hope you get the result of your liking :)

Comment: Why Are All Of Your Words Capitalised?

Comment: Many People in Marketing Use Title Case Indiscriminately - Perhaps This Has Long-Term Exposure Effects For Graphic Designers About Which We Should Be Concerned?

Comment: The answer would look even more leet with random case : `dRaG yoUr CursOR ABoVe iMAGe tO CHANgE tHe LOcATioN OF YOur gRAdIenT AnD CHAnge SCaLe sLidEr TO DEFInE sPReAd areA.`

Comment: @DesignPhoenix - could you please avoid typing your answers with unnecessary initial capitals. Let's try to show a good example to would-be designers who might happen upon your otherwise good answers. Thanks.

Comment: @BillyKerr Couldn't you submit an edit to fix that then?

Comment: @LiefdeWen - Yes, I could easily edit it, but there's a point of principle here. Why should I waste my time fixing something the answerer could easily fix by **not** doing it in the first place.

Comment: Sorry guys; maybe it's my bad habbit haha will try to keep in mind next time :P

Comment: @Billy Kerr Sorry :) will keep eye on my next answer for not repeting this again :)